# Control GPIO of ESP32 using Bluetooth

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, esp32, gpio

I’m using ESP32 to control relays using MQTT ( both over Arduino and MicroPython ).

For special cases, and not for everyday operation, I wish to control a specific GPIO over Bluetooth ( a reset irq).

Comment: OK, Now what have you already tried? (edit the question to include more detail)

Comment: I did not find any piece of code regarding such implementation